# Storyboard : Object doesn't displaying

Tags: ios, storyboard, appearance, xcode6-beta6

I have on a special case :

[image]

Yesterday It worked cool. But now I don't know why this problem is here.

You can see that the view always contains the object like email/password textfield, background etc but it's in transparence. And in the view, it doesn't appear. When compiling/executing, it works, it display background, input, etc .. the problem is just in the storyboard.

So someone know what is that ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using different sizes, check on bottom center storyboard for "

> wAny hAny

" and change for other else and it`ll appear

[image: Like that]

Sry for bad english